# Wrong redirect in rails_admin with admin and user models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

In my app I have two devise models admin and user.

My rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.main_app_name = ['MyApp', 'Admin']
  config.current_user_method { current_admin } # auto-generated
  config.authenticate_with {} # leave it to authorize
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.new_admin_session_path unless current_admin
  end
end
```

And in my routes.rb

```
devise_for :admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
devise_for :users
```

When I access /admin the app redirects me to /users/sign_in

What is wrong, why I am not redirected to /admins/sign_in?

Comment: If i'm already logged with a regular user, when access /admin my app redirects me to /admins/sign_in

Comment: For my idea there should be one model User as admin is also a use. you can provide authorization using can can gem.

Comment: Try putting the line `RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'` above the line `devise_for :admins`. Rails routing takes precedence from top to bottom, so it might be routing based on your first line and never hitting the second one.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. 
I have fixed it after making some changes into routes.rb

can you please try the same and let me know, if that helps you.

```
  devise_for :admins
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admins', :as => 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users

    Examples are here.

        http://madhulata.in/admins
        and
        http://madhulata.in
```